# Error 2500 when trying to get Facebook Email in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I try to get email address of a user logged in via Facebook Module. But  get error every time {"error":"An error code 2500 has occured. An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}

My code is:

```
var viewClick = function() {
    fb.logout();
    fb.initialize(); 
    fb.authorize();
};

var facebookLogged = function(e) {

    fb.requestWithGraphPath("me?fields=name,email,first_name,last_name", {}, 'GET', function(result) {
        Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(result))
       // var data = JSON.parse(e.result);
});
};
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({exitOnClose: true, navBarHidden: true, fullscreen: true, orientationModes: [
        Ti.UI.PORTRAIT,
        Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT,      
    ],
    backgroundColor: '#f0f2f2'
}); 

var fb = require('facebook');

if(Ti.Platform.osname === 'android') {

    window.fbProxy = fb.createActivityWorker({lifecycleContainer: window});
}

    //fb.setLoginBehavior(fb.LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE);
fb.permissions = ['email'];

window.open();


var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
}); 

view.addEventListener('click', viewClick);

window.add(view);
fb.addEventListener('login', facebookLogged);
```

I also tried to provide access token code by modyfing requestWithGraphPath parameters:

```
fb.requestWithGraphPath("me?fields=name,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=" + e.source.accessToken, {}, 'GET', function(result) {}
```

but in such case I get infromation that accessToken is malformed.
TiFacebookModule: (main) [117,178060] requestWithGraphPath callback error: Malformed access token [Here is access token value]?access_token=[Here is access token value]

What I do wrong? How to get Email from FB? Any help deeply appreciated.

Comment: ps: don't post your token

Comment: It is fake account (just for testing app) so no big deal :). But I will clean it.

Comment: where exactly are you getting and passing the auth token?

Comment: @developer82: access token and user id is sent via returned object (e) in facebookLogged function. This function is invoked when 'login' event is fired. As I wrote i did two approach without sending access token (error 2500):
`fb.requestWithGraphPath("me?fields=name,email,first_name,last_name", {}, 'GET', function(result) {`
or sending a token (malformed access token error):
`fb.requestWithGraphPath("me?fields=name,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=" + e.source.accessToken, {}, 'GET', function(result) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and this is what I do, for Android the requestWithGraphPath doesn't work like its IOS counterpart and the documentation is not updated either. You need to send the fields in the object and only the "me" in the first parameter:

```
var facebookLogged = function(e) {
    fb.requestWithGraphPath("me", { fields: "name,email,first_name,last_name"}, 'GET', function(result) {
        Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(result))
        // var data = JSON.parse(e.result);
    });
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. It works like a charm on Android. How do you receive email for iOS because I am stuck with same problem there.

Comment: For IOS "me?fields=name,email,first_name,last_name" worked just fine, what do you get on the request response?

Comment: I get {"result":"{\"id\":\"1498651573764560\",\"last_name\":\"Kars\",\"name\":\"Eren Kars\",\"first_name\":\"Eren\"}","success":true,"path":"me?fields=name,email,first_name,last_name"}

Comment: Problem on iOS was caused by not adding all required LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in tiapp.xml